# Use cases of IList<T> interface

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working for a while with standard collections and today I encountered this situation again. TL;DR: You can never be safe with `IList<T>`.

Explanation: today I encountered an interface `Foo(IList<Bar> bars)` which I could use with my `Bar[]` local and I thought `hmm, it may modify the collection so I will get an exception while attempting to insert a value into array. Let's check what's inside`. After some investigation I finally found some call for `Remove` method which makes an array completely unusable in this case. But you won't get it at compile time.

Is there any *practical* situation where you need `IList<T>`? In 99% of code I have ever seen the only two classes implementing `IList<T>` is `List<T>` and `T[]`, but the only common mutating operation you can safely use in both cases is an indexer. So isn't it better to always use `List<T>` when you modify a collection or `IReadOnlyList<T>` when you don't? It seems very uncommon that you will receive an instance of `IList<T>` which is not of this two basic types. But you get a compile-time safety and bacon.

Comment: Actually I use it quite often with a combination of `ObservableCollection<T>` in WPF :). But you are absolutely right, if the variable/member/property/field or returntype is not ment to be editted, it should not expose `IList<T>`, but rather the ones you mentioned or the simplest `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Use the interface when you need a contract. Use the concrete when you don't. If you are a lib author, try to use the interface because some people implement `IList<T>` on their own types.

Comment: `IReadOnlyList` is a very nice idea. It's also a very late addition to the .NET Framework. `IList` was an obvious generalization of `List` way back when.

Comment: @vcsjones: Just to extend what I think is part of the OP's question: is there any use case for `IList<T>` over the more generalized `IEnumerable<T>`? I can't think of any, and I think the OP can't either.

Comment: @Flater `IEnumerable<T>` isn't mutable. You can't add to it or really treat it as a "collection". an `IEnumerable<T>` might be a `yield return` generator. `IList<T>` also implies a "materialized" collection.

Comment: Suppose you *don't* need to add or remove elements to the list, you just need to rearrange them. You're an in-place sort function. What's the type of your argument? `List<T>`? No, arrays would also work. `T[]`? No, now I have to copy my `List<T>` to an array first. `IEnumerable<T>`? No, that may not even be a collection and certainly has no efficient `.Count`. `IReadOnlyList<T>`? No, I'm changing the contents. `IList<T>` is the nicest interface in this case, even though it (and the rest of the hierarchy) really doesn't cleanly express what we're after.

Comment: @JeroenMostert after changing `IList<T>` to `LIst<T>` i just found two bugs where someone acually was setting an array in this property. And just because of luck it never explode at runtime. And I said about indexers, but in most cases you don't need it. And if you need, you'd probably want to force `LIst<T>` even when array may be processed.

Comment: You asked if there was ever any practical situation; I think an in-place sort qualifies as practical (if rare, given the predefined sorting algorithms). I see really no need to "force" `List<T>` in this case. It's fairly cheap if you're wrapping an entire array that way, not so much if you want to pass an [`ArraySegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1hsbd92d). `IList<T>` is indeed an abstraction of limited use and it should be carefully considered, but it's not *completely* useless.

Comment: I agree with the majority of your sentiment but this is really you railing against the way in which .Net has evolved and the lack of foresight in the initial design. You already know the answer, as does anybody who understands the "question."

Comment: The issue is not so much that `IList` is bad, it is that arrays should never have implemented it. But given that is the situation we are in, I will generally push people to use either `List`, `[]` or `IReadOnlyList` (depending on their mutability needs) - so that expected behaviour is clear.

Comment: The fact that `T[]` implements `IList<T>` is a bit flawed, unfortunately, since `T[]` belongs somewhere between a `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IList<T>` (its indexer has a setter, meaning individual elements can be modified, but the size of the array is immutable). Basically what @mjwills said a moment ago. :)

Comment: Simple solution, don't return an array as an `IList<T>`. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by answering your specific question:

> Why do we need a `IList<T>` interface

It is the only interface that provides mutable indexed access - contract for `List<T>` and `T[]` - so they can be interchangeably passed as an argument to functions that need such a contract.

Not to mention, when you want to roll your own implementation. For example, I want to expose a `File` as an `IList<char>` - it might not be the best idea, but you get the drift.

I agree that `IList<T>` is a poor choice of interface, since adding and removing an element is not what an array naturally supports.

**Now to the bigger picture:** You may ignore this as this is very subjective

.NET framework has done a poor job with its collection interfaces. Not only they are not in a single namespace, but they have evolved over time - which means there is a lot of code out there (including in the BCL) which use the "best" available interface as of when it was written, which might be a bad choice as of today.

I believe they should have started with interfaces like below - perhaps with better names :)

```
interface IEnumerable<T> {
    // just like we currently have
}

// currently called IReadOnlyCollection<T>
interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    int Count { get; }
}

// currently called as IReadOnlyList<T>
interface IIndexedCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
    T this[int index] { get; }
}

// currently called as ICollection<T>, but doesn't inherit from IReadOnlyCollection
interface IMutableCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
    void Add(T item);
    bool Remove(T item);
    void Clear();
}

// We don't have this at all - OP's case
interface IArray<T> : IIndexedCollection<T> {
    T this[int index] { get; set; }
}

// currently exists as IList<T>, but inheritance is very different
interface IList<T> : IArray<T>, IMutableCollection<T> {
    void Insert(int index, T item);
    void RemoveAt(int index);
}
```

Comment: The first half is an answer, the second a discussion point. Your design may be better than what we have now but in 10 years time, someone will want rewrite it and break compatibility with legacy code. Either way, the point is moot.

Comment: @Jodrell I agree, but the second part provides some context into root cause of the problem

Comment: Ok, so why have `IMutableCollection` wouldn't it be better to have `IWhatever` where `Add`, `Remove` and `Clear` return new immutable collections. etc. etc.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/ plenty to think about here.

Comment: @Jodrell: this design is objectively much better than .NET's. Throwing runtime exceptions for "missing functionality" is a sign of poor OOP practices, this was obvious to any programmer looking at .NET 2.0 interfaces. The interfaces suggested here would pretty much cover all the existing cases correctly. For example, methods parsing a byte buffer have to access the count and individual elements, but should never be able to mutate the collection. Prior to `IReadOnlyList<T>` in .NET 4.5, this was impossible; and now that they added it, `IList<T>` *doesn't* implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: Agreed but, this site is for answers about what we have, not discussions about what might be. Here we should learn about the existing Leaky Abstractions. We can discuss the next set on user voice (I jest) or at our next design meeting. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/